# Omitting columns when importing CSV into Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, shell, csv, unix

Imagine that you have the following data in a CSV:

```
Name, Age, Gender
Jake, 40, M
Bill, 17, M
Suzie, 21, F
```

Is it possible to exclude the Age variable when importing the above CSV? My current approach is to simply use the `cut` shell command.

**Update**

iluvcapra has a great answer for small CSVs. However, for very large CSVs this approach is inefficient. For example, imagine that the above CSV was very large, 30Gb lets say. Loading all that Age data only to immediately remove is a waste of time. With this in mind, is there a more efficient way to load subsets of columns into sqlite databases?

I suspect that the best option is to use the shell command `cut` to cull out unnecessary columns. Is that intuition correct? Is it common to use shell commands to pre-process CSV files into more sqlite friendly versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a temporary table with the age column, and then use an INSERT... SELECT to move the data from the temporary table into your main one:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE _csv_import (name text, age integer, gender text);
.separator ","
.import file.csv test

INSERT INTO names_genders (name, gender) SELECT name, gender
    FROM _csv_import WHERE 1;
DROP TABLE _csv_import;
```

---

EDIT:  Updating into a view with a phantom age column:

```
CREATE VIEW names_ages_genders AS 
    SELECT (name, 0 AS age ,gender) FROM names_genders;
CREATE TRIGGER lose_age
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON names_ages_genders
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO names_genders (name, gender) 
            VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.gender)
    END;
```

This will create a view called `names_ages_genders` that will say everybody is zero years old, and will silently drop the age field from any `INSERT` statement called on it.  Not tested!  (I'm actually not sure `.import` can import into views.)

Comment: Thanks!  This is great for my example.  However, for large CSV  files (several GB) this is rather inefficient.  I don't like the idea of loading all the data only to remove some data immediately after loading it.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

It all happens in RAM if you use a temp table.  You could also create a `VIEW` over your import table that had one extra column that didn't map to any column in an `INSTEAD OF` `INSERT` hook.  That way you could import it with a single `.import`, inserting into the view instead of the table.

Comment: `cut` works too, but both `cut` and `.import` don't actually do the Right Thing with CSV files, they don't handle the escaping properly.  I think there's a sqlite module that will map a CSV file to a virtual table [your mileage may vary](https://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles)

Comment: (Added view/insert trigger to answer)

Comment: I think you mean to say .import file.csv _csv_import

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid reading more than necessary into SQLite, and if you wish to avoid the hazards of using standard text-processing tools (such as `cut` and `awk`) on CSV files, one possibility would be to use your favorite `csv2tsv` converter (*) along the following lines:

```
csv2tsv input.csv | cut -f 1,3- > tmp.tsv

cat << EOF | sqlite3 demo.db
drop table if exists demo;
.mode csv
.separator "\t"
.import tmp.tsv demo
EOF

/bin/rm tmp.tsv
```

Note, though, that if input.csv has literal tabs or newlines or escaped double-quotes, then 
 whether the above will have the desired effect will depend on the csv2tsv that is used.

### (*) csv2tsv

In case you don't have ready access to a suitable csv2tsv converter, here is a simple python3 script that does the job, handling embedded literal newlines, tabs, and the two-character sequences `"\t"` and `"\n"`, in the CSV:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Take care of embedded tabs and newlines in the CSV

import csv, re, sys

if len(sys.argv) > 2 or (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '--help'):
    sys.exit("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " [input.csv [output.tsv]]")

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    out=open(sys.argv[2], 'w+')
else:
    out=sys.stdout

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    csvfile=sys.stdin
else:
    csvfile=open(sys.argv[1])

# tabs and newlines ...
def edit(s):
  s=re.sub(r'\\t', r'\\\\t', s)
  s=re.sub(r'\\n', r'\\\\n', s)
  s=re.sub('\t', r'\\t', s)
  return re.sub('\n', r'\\n', s)

reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
for row in reader:
    line=""
    for s in row:
       s=edit(s)
       if len(line) == 0:
          line = s
       else:
          line += '\t' + s
    print(line)
```